# How do you drain a carburetor?

Tags: maintenance, chainsaw

Chainsaw manufacturers recommend "draining the carburetor" before putting the chainsaw into storage for a period of disuse. This would seem to be a good idea as otherwise the fuel could damage the seals in the carburetor.

How do you drain a carburetor?

Answer (score 4):

Chain saws have what is called a diaphragm carburetor as opposed to the carburetor with a float. The float bowl in those types hold gas and need to be drained and usually have a drain plug. The carb on the saw  holds very little gas so just run it until it conks out for lack of gas.

Comment: First, empty the fuel tank or turn off the fuel supply.

Comment: That kinda goes without saying about the conking out for lack of gas